# zsh glob pattern to match all files except one, does not work, despite EXTENDED_GLOB being set

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have a directory containing several files:

```
$ ls tdir
xx  yy zz
```

I'm looking for a `zsh` glob pattern, which expands to all (non-dot)-files except `xx`. This is what I tried:

```
$ set -o EXTENDED_GLOB
$ echo tdir/*~xx
tdir/xx tdir/yy tdir/zz
```

As we can see, this does not work; `*~xx` is not expanded in the way I expected. How do I write this correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `glob~filter` (and-not) operator applies a filter as a negative pattern matching on the result of the whole glob.

That allows things like:

```
grep foo ./**/*~*/.svn/*(.mh-1)
```

for instance.

Here, you'd need:

```
echo tdir/*~tdir/xx
```

Or:

```
echo tdir/*~*/xx
```

Or:

```
echo tdir/(*~xx)
```

Or use the `^` negation operator instead:

```
echo tdir/^xx
```